# Why doesn't this code work to get the checked checkbox?

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

```
function selectedClass(){
if(!empty($_POST['checklist_class'])) {                  
    foreach($_POST['checklist_class'] as $id) {
       //stuff
    }
}
```

}

I've used identical code for another set of checkboxes and it works, but when i try it with the one below it doesn't. I would really appreciate some help!
Here's the HTML code:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id ="form1">
 <div class="multiselect">
            <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
              <select>
                <option>Choose classes</option>
              </select>
              <div class="overSelect"></div>
            </div>                
            <div id="checkboxes">
              <label for ='1'>
              <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'checklist_class[]' value = '1'> One
              </label>
              <label for ='2'>
              <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'checklist_class[]' value = '2'> Two
              </label>
              <label for ='3'>
              <input type = 'checkbox' name = 'checklist_class[]' value = '3'> Three
              </label>                  
            </div>
          </div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The `<label>` tag is associated with the `id` property of the `<input>` and without any `id` attribute that does is incorrect.

Comment: I'm actually interested in the values. I am using them as database table ids and the goal is to loop through them and run queries.

Comment: Where is your form tag?

Comment: Your `<label>` tags accomplish nothing. But if you have the correct `<form>` tag (not shown!) and something that results in the form being submitted (such as a submit button or JavaScript code -- again (not shown!), then it should work. But you don't even describe **what the problem you are having is** ("not working" is not a good description). This is not an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code is inside a form and there is a submit button. So far i've localized the problem to be in the foreach statement. It doesn't execute at all but I can't figure out why.

Comment: And the form specifies `method='post'`? and you are sure function `selectedClass` is being called?

Comment: Please show more code. Debug output. The whole form. Details please!!

Comment: I updated the code. Everything else works as i've tried it with other form components. The only problem is the foreach block that's not executing.

Comment: Is the data what you expect?  `var_dump($_POST);`